# How to enable CSS 3 in Internet Explorer 7?

Tags: css

I want to enable CSS 3 in IE7. It works perfect in Firefox, but in IE it doesn't.
I downloaded files from google code (IE8.js - DOMAssistantCompressed-2.7.4.js) to run css3 in IE but this does not work.

Comment: Mark your other questions as answered first if you want new answers.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what you're looking for: http://selectivizr.com/

Basically it allows you to use CSS3 selectors in Internet Explorer.

Comment: +1 Those of you looking for CSS3 *properties*, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

IE7 has limited support for CSS3:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28VS.85%29.aspx

But I think you have to use a strict XHTML DOCTYPE in order for them to work.

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 is not supported in Internet Explorer 7

Comment: @Downvoter - would you like to explain why? For all intents and purposes IE7 does not support CSS3.

Answer (score 0):

Use [CSS3PIE](http://css3pie.com/) to get the following in IE6-9:

- border-radius
- box-shadow
- border-image
- CSS3 Backgrounds
- Gradients
- RGBA Color Values

And more!